# "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me" error message on Sharepoint

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, calculated-columns

I try to add a new calculated column to sharepoint list that will show elapsed day. I enter **name** and write a **formula like**;

=ABS(ROUND(Today-Created;0))

**The data type returned from this formula is:** Single line of text

When I want to save I get an error like

> Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and
>   Me.

Comment: So long answer and workarounds at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Calculated Column Values Only Recalculate As Needed**

The values in SharePoint columns--even in calculated columns--are stored in SharePoint's underlying SQL Server database.

The calculations in calculated columns are not performed upon page load; rather, they are recalculated only whenever an item is changed (in which case the formula is recalculated just for that specific item), or whenever the column formula is changed (in which case the formula is recalculated for all items).

(As a side note, this is the reason why in SharePoint 2010 you cannot create or change a calculated column on a list that has more than the list view threshold of 5000 items; it would require a mass update of values in all those items, which could impact database performance.)

Thus, in order for calculated columns to accurately store "volatile" values like "Me" and "Today", SharePoint would need to somehow constantly recalculate those column values and continuously update the column values in the database. This simply isn't possible.

**Alternatives to Calculated Columns**

I suggest taking a different approach entirely instead of using a calculated column for this purpose.

1. **Conditional Formatting**: You can apply conditional formatting to highlight records that meet certain criteria. This can be done using SharePoint Designer or HTML/JavaScript.
2. **Filtered List views**: Since views of lists are queried and generated in real time, you can use volatile values in list view filters. You can set up a list view web part that only shows items where `Created` is equal to `[Today]`. Since you can place multiple list view web parts on one page, you could have one section for today's items, and another web part for all the other items, giving you a visual separation.
3. **A workflow, timer job, or scheduled task**: You can use a repeating process to set the value of a normal (non-calculated) column on a daily basis. You need to be careful with this approach to ensure good performance; you wouldn't want it to query for and update every item in the list if the list has surpassed the list view threshold, for example.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

I found some conversations about this issue. Many people suggest to creating a new Date Time column, visible is false, default value is **Today's Date** and it will be named as **Today**. Then we can use this column in our formulas.

I tried this suggestion and yes error is gone and formula is accepted but calculated columns' values are wrong. I setted column Today is visible and checked, it was empty. Default value Today's Date was not working. When I looking for a solution for this issue I deleted column Today carelessly. Then I realized calculated columns' values are right.

<del>Finally; I don't know what is trick but before using **Today** keyword in your formulas if you create a column named as Today and after your formula saving if you delete Today column, it is working.</del>

### UPDATE

After @Thriggle's answer I realized this approach doesn't work like a charm. Yes, formula doesn't cause an error when calculated column saving but it works correctly only first time, in the next day the calculated column shows old values, because its values are static as Thriggle [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36181855/820031).